# AOSP Emulator Images not running

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, qemu

I'm trying to create an AVD Emulator image from the AOSP source code that I can run using the standard Android Emulator on my M1 Macbook (arm64).

I've followed all the standard steps starting from https://source.android.com/docs/setup/start/initializing which includes:

- Setting up the build environment
- Cloning the sources
- Choosing a lunch target (`sdk_phone_arm64`) as mentioned here https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/avd
- Creating the build with `m`
- Creating the emulator images with `make emu_img_zip` (on Android 13 / 14) and `make sdk sdk_repo` (on Android 11 / 12) as mentioned here https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/avd
- Creating an AVD with the generated system image files

So far only the Android 12 build (from the android12-release branch from here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+refs) has given me an emulator that actually boots up and is usable.

`android11-release`, `android13-release`, `android14-release` have all generated the builds fine but the emulator never boots and appears to be in a loop, here are kernel logs from the Android 13 build, this appears to be the relevant place where the kernel panics:

```
[    0.359454][    T1] uart-pl011 9000000.pl011: no DMA platform data
[    0.359992][    T1] VFS: Cannot open root device "(null)" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
[    0.360612][    T1] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
[    0.361315][    T1] 0100            8192 ram0
[    0.361317][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.361912][    T1] 0101            8192 ram1
[    0.361913][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.362513][    T1] 0102            8192 ram2
[    0.362514][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.363177][    T1] 0103            8192 ram3
[    0.363178][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.363761][    T1] 0104            8192 ram4
[    0.363761][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.364361][    T1] 0105            8192 ram5
[    0.364361][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.364976][    T1] 0106            8192 ram6
[    0.364977][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.365559][    T1] 0107            8192 ram7
[    0.365560][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.366179][    T1] 0108            8192 ram8
[    0.366180][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.366777][    T1] 0109            8192 ram9
[    0.366777][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.367363][    T1] 010a            8192 ram10
[    0.367363][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.367949][    T1] 010b            8192 ram11
[    0.367949][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.368532][    T1] 010c            8192 ram12
[    0.368533][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.369119][    T1] 010d            8192 ram13
[    0.369119][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.369730][    T1] 010e            8192 ram14
[    0.369730][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.370359][    T1] 010f            8192 ram15
[    0.370360][    T1]  (driver?)
[    0.370951][    T1] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    0.371710][    T1] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.15.41-android13-8-00029-g24d27dff64c4-ab9178016 #1
[    0.359088][    T1] Hardware name: linux,ranchu (DT)
[    0.359470][    T1] Call trace:
[    0.359766][    T1]  dump_backtrace.cfi_jt+0x0/0x8
[    0.360137][    T1]  dump_stack_lvl+0x80/0xb8
[    0.360472][    T1]  panic+0x180/0x444
[    0.360764][    T1]  mount_block_root+0x1ac/0x270
[    0.361123][    T1]  mount_root+0x68/0x90
[    0.361454][    T1]  prepare_namespace+0x164/0x1e8
[    0.361825][    T1]  kernel_init_freeable+0x120/0x19c
[    0.362282][    T1]  kernel_init+0x40/0x36c
[    0.362606][    T1]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x20
[    0.362938][    T1] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[    0.363367][    T1] Kernel Offset: disabled
[    0.363708][    T1] CPU features: 0x0,00000281,4b354ee8
[    0.364112][    T1] Memory Limit: none
[    0.000000][    T0] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x00000000]
[    0.000000][    T0] Linux version 5.15.41-android13-8-00029-g24d27dff64c4-ab9178016 (build-user@build-host) (Android (8508608, based on r450784e) clang version 14.0.7 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb0cca074e9238af8b4106c30add4418f6), LLD 14.0.7) #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 14 19:05:44 UTC 2022
[    0.000000][    T0] Machine model: linux,ranchu
[    0.000000][    T0] Stack Depot is disabled
[    0.000000][    T0] KVM is not available. Ignoring kvm-arm.mode
[    0.000000][    T0] printk: debug: skip boot console de-registration.
```

Not sure if these emulator logs from the start are relevant but may be helpful

```
❯ emulator @Test_Device2 -show-kernel
INFO    | Android emulator version 33.1.13.0 (build_id 10332831) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /Users/username_here/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-33/default/arm64-v8a/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 40462
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_posture_requested(int) ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_posture_selection_dialog() ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_resizable_requested(PresetEmulatorSizeType) ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_resizable_dialog() ((null):0, (null))
library_mode host gpu mode host
WARNING | cannot add library /Users/username_here/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
INFO    | added library /Users/username_here/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
```

I'm not changing anything on the AOSP source code, and all the builds succeed fine with identical steps. How can I get a working Android 13 / 14 emulator image?

Stock arm64 emulator images downloaded through Android Studio work fine.

I can't run the `emulator` command on the machine I am building on, as that is on a cloud linux machine that does not support virtualization.

Answer (score 1):

That is funny because currently I have the exact same problem.

In my build I can find the file:

```
out/target/product/emulator_x86_64/sdk-repo-linux-system-images.zip
```

I guess you can find a similar file. This zip is the AVD image.

There is an [official guide](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/avd) (you already know it) but it only works for Android 12 and below. Because it says on Android 12 and below you can also find a `repo-sys-img.xml` in the build. This file is needed to add the AVD to Android Studio. But what about newer Android versions? It says nothing and I also cannot find such a file in my Android 15 build.

The needed `repo-sys-img.xml` is like this file: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-3.xml.
I have this link from the screenshot below. Normally you can build this file but as it is not in the build the only idea I have right now is to take this XML file from the link and edit it.

I added a question to the [android-building](https://groups.google.com/g/android-building) Google group yesterday but it hasn't been accepted yet.

This is where the XML file has to be added (I guess it has to start with `file://...`):
[image]

Comment: I actually didn't try the whole repo xml thing, I found that if you use the zip AVD image, extract the files and put them in the folder with the existing Android Studio system images, they show up when you try to create a new AVD. Just make sure there is a `package.xml` which shows the details of the build, you can check the contents from a normal image downloaded from Android studio.